# File Upload to ASP.net from React.js

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I need to develop File Upload fucntion using React.js, and cannot understand how it works at backend side using asp.net

At react side, I am trying to submit file with formData but at server-side,
function is

```
public Sample<int> saveDoc(int Id, short documentItemID, string filePath, 
    Stream fileStream){
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    Data = memoryStream.ToArray()
}
```

I have no idea what to input to (Stream fileStream) from frontend.

My frontend is

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Id', id);
formData.append('documentItemID', docID);
formData.append('filePath', filepath);
formData.append('fileStream', ???);
axios.post(endpoint,formData, 'multipart/form-data')
```

I can only handle javascript and php, so need php middleware to transform file to stream format? Can we do it from frontend?

Comment: is it mvc 5 or webforms?

Comment: also add your clientside code whcich is responsible for sending the files

Comment: if you want to get you files try Request.Files for webforms

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier I updated frontend codes